# Bootstrap dropdown select option but for a form instead of <a>

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a **form** with bootstrap dropdown. But when I try to make it to a form 'select'  it looses all the 'primary' styling.  How do I keep that?

```
How do I convert this to have the <option value="x"></option> format? 
but still having the same primary-button look? Thanks..


<div class="dropdown">
<button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" type="button">Choose an option&nbsp;</button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
       <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Option 1</a>
       <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Option 2</a>
       <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Option 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: You can't style a selectbox, you will have to build something like a custom solution (which you already have)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the below link. You have to use a bootstrap-select library to meet your requirment.

**The link you can follow:**

[Trying to use bootstrap-select for my dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62006061/trying-to-use-bootstrap-select-for-my-dropdown)

**The package link**

https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap-select

HTML

```
<select class="selectpicker">
  <option>Mustard</option>
  <option>Ketchup</option>
  <option>Barbecue</option>
</select>
```

JQuery

```
$('.my-select').selectpicker();
```

Change your select option and button as you want using CSS.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" type="button">Choose an option&nbsp;
  <select class="dropdown-menu">
    <option class="dropdown-item" href="#">Option 1</option>
    <option class="dropdown-item" href="#">Option 2</option>
    <option class="dropdown-item" href="#">Option 3</option>
  </select>
  </button>
</div>
```

Or you can use this also

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" type="button">Choose an option&nbsp;
  <select class="dropdown-menu">
    <option value="">Option 1</option>
    <option value="">Option 2</option>
    <option value="" >Option 3</option>
  </select>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this gives me a dropdown and a second dropdown menu just below it.